# How to select and deselect in a crossword game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, im doing a crossword game in Unity Engine, and when i select (with my left click button) a word, the white tiles should turn green (which occurs), but when i stop holding my left mouse click button, it does not turns white again as you can see on the print [image: here is the print i told you]

And the code is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System; 

public class Selecionar : MonoBehaviour, ISelectHandler, IPointerClickHandler, IDeselectHandler {

private int acertos;
public static HashSet<Selecionar> todosMeusSelecionaveis = new HashSet<Selecionar>();
public static HashSet<Selecionar> selecionado = new HashSet<Selecionar>();

Renderer myRenderer;

[SerializeField]
Material materialNaoSelecionado;
[SerializeField]
Material materialSelecionado;


void Awake()
{
    todosMeusSelecionaveis.Add(this);
    myRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

public void OnDeselect(BaseEventData eventData)
{
    myRenderer.material = materialNaoSelecionado;
}

public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
        DeselectAll(eventData);
    }
    OnSelect(eventData);
}

public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
{
    selecionado.Add(this);
    myRenderer.material = materialSelecionado;
}
public static void DeselectAll (BaseEventData eventData){
    foreach (Selecionar selecionavel in selecionado)
    {
        selecionavel.OnDeselect(eventData);
    }
    selecionado.Clear();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should `return` inside the `if` statement on `OnPointerClick`. When it enters, it executes `DeselectAll` followed by `OnSelect`.

Either do:

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
        DeselectAll(eventData);
        return; // <----
    }
    OnSelect(eventData);
}
```

or:

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
        DeselectAll(eventData);
    } else {
        OnSelect(eventData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't worked, sadly the green tiles  continue green when i stop holding my left click mouse button

Comment: Do you have event handlers like `MouseKeyUp` and `MouseKeyDown`? I would try handling on them instead of `MouseClick`. Maybe your `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)` is never getting `true`?

Comment: Event Handlers? And how do i use MouseClick?

Comment: By the way, the Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) is getting true, since i click with my mouse :P